# Telegram bot - answer inline query with plain text?

Tags: telegram

I'm trying to make an inline Telegram bot that would modify user input in a certain way. Because of that I wanted to answer the query with simple text, but that doesn't seem possible and I'm wondering if it's really not or I'm missing something.

According to Telegram, there's [20 handy result types](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinequeryresult), yet there doesn't seem to be simple plain text. Is that really the case? How can I achieve my desired result then?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same exact issue and solved it with the `InlineQueryResultArticle`.

Example code for your `OnInlineQuery` Method:

```c-sharp
// Check for invalid queries
if (e.InlineQuery.Query == null)
    return;
if (e.InlineQuery.Query == "")
    return;


InlineQueryResultBase[] results = {
    new InlineQueryResultArticle(
        // id's should be unique for each type of response
        id: "1",
        // Title of the option
        title: "sample title",
        // This is what is returned
        new InputTextMessageContent("text that is returned") {ParseMode = Telegram.Bot.Types.Enums.ParseMode.Default })
    {
        // This is just the description shown for the option
        Description = "You could also put your output text for a preview here too."
    }
};

// Send the response
try
{
    // If your method is not async you have to remove the await
    await client.AnswerInlineQueryAsync(e.InlineQuery.Id, results);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    Console.WriteLine($"Error responding to Inline Query! {ex.Message}");
}
```

Comment: What language is this one?

Comment: @FerranMaylinch That's C#

Answer (score 0):

Use "InlineQueryResultArticle" and either set the value of "url" to undefined or do not set "url" fileld.